# Python generate a multi range values within a list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to generate a multi range values within a list. My code is given below

```
drop_cols = [6,21,range(38:14*16:16),range(229:229+14*16:16)]
```

My present output is :

```
drop_cols = [6,21,range(38:14*16:16),range(229:229+14*16:16)]
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My expected output is:

```
drop_cols = [6,21,38,....,229,..]
```

Comment: `range` uses commas to separate the fields... looks like you're probably after `[6, 21, *range(38, 14*16, 16), *range(229, 220 + 14*16, 16)]` ?

Comment: or with `np.r_`: `np.r_[6, 21, 38:14*16:16, 229:229+14*16:16]`

Comment: @JonClements It worked. I actually forgot that `range` uses commas. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `np.r_`:

```
drop_cols = np.r_[2:5, 10:15, 19]
drop_cols
```

Output:

```
array([ 2,  3,  4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19])
```

Comment: But my requirement is a different ranges with different starting pionts.